# Error initializing class com.jacob.com.Dispatch

Tags: java

I have jacob.jar in the WEB-INF\lib directory and jacob-1.16.1-x86.dll in the windows\system32 directory.

Works ok on a development box. On the production machine it falls over. I am Running Tomcat 7. Log contains:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.jacob.com.Dispatch
```

on this line:

```
Dispatch oCompy = new Dispatch("Compy.Connect")
```

Any suggestions?

EDIT:
As per the suggestion I have gone through the source of jacob but I cannot find any import statements that reference a library that would not normally be available. I will include the list here. I am relatively new to Java so maybe I am missing something:

```
jacob-1.16.1\src\com\jacob\activex\activexcomponent.java - import com.jacob.com.Dispatch;
jacob-1.16.1\src\com\jacob\activex\activexcomponent.java - import com.jacob.com.JacobObject;
jacob-1.16.1\src\com\jacob\activex\activexcomponent.java - import com.jacob.com.Variant;
jacob-1.16.1\src\com\jacob\activex\activexdispatchevents.java - import com.jacob.com.InvocationProxy;
jacob-1.16.1\src\com\jacob\activex\activexdispatchevents.java - import com.jacob.com.Dispatch;
jacob-1.16.1\src\com\jacob\activex\activexdispatchevents.java - import com.jacob.com.DispatchEvents;
jacob-1.16.1\src\com\jacob\activex\activexinvocationproxy.java - import com.jacob.com.Variant;
jacob-1.16.1\src\com\jacob\activex\activexinvocationproxy.java - import com.jacob.com.NotImplementedException;
jacob-1.16.1\src\com\jacob\activex\activexinvocationproxy.java - import java.lang.reflect.Method;
jacob-1.16.1\src\com\jacob\activex\activexinvocationproxy.java - import com.jacob.com.InvocationProxy;
jacob-1.16.1\src\com\jacob\activex\activexinvocationproxy.java - import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
jacob-1.16.1\src\com\jacob\com\dateutilities.java - import java.util.Calendar;
jacob-1.16.1\src\com\jacob\com\dateutilities.java - import java.util.Date;
jacob-1.16.1\src\com\jacob\com\invocationproxyallvariants.java - import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
jacob-1.16.1\src\com\jacob\com\invocationproxyallvariants.java - import java.lang.reflect.Method;
jacob-1.16.1\src\com\jacob\com\jacobreleaseinfo.java - import java.util.Properties;
jacob-1.16.1\src\com\jacob\com\jacobreleaseinfo.java - import java.io.InputStream;
jacob-1.16.1\src\com\jacob\com\jacobreleaseinfo.java - import java.io.IOException;
jacob-1.16.1\src\com\jacob\com\libraryloader.java - import java.util.Set;
jacob-1.16.1\src\com\jacob\com\libraryloader.java - import java.util.ResourceBundle;
jacob-1.16.1\src\com\jacob\com\libraryloader.java - import java.util.Locale;
jacob-1.16.1\src\com\jacob\com\libraryloader.java - import java.util.MissingResourceException;
jacob-1.16.1\src\com\jacob\com\libraryloader.java - import java.util.Enumeration;
jacob-1.16.1\src\com\jacob\com\libraryloader.java - import java.util.HashSet;
jacob-1.16.1\src\com\jacob\com\rot.java - import java.util.WeakHashMap;
jacob-1.16.1\src\com\jacob\com\rot.java - import java.util.Map;
jacob-1.16.1\src\com\jacob\com\rot.java - import java.util.Iterator;
jacob-1.16.1\src\com\jacob\com\rot.java - import java.util.HashMap;
jacob-1.16.1\src\com\jacob\com\variant.java - import java.util.Date;
jacob-1.16.1\src\com\jacob\com\variant.java - import java.math.BigInteger;
jacob-1.16.1\src\com\jacob\com\variant.java - import java.math.BigDecimal;
jacob-1.16.1\src\com\jacob\com\variantutilities.java - import java.util.Date;
jacob-1.16.1\src\com\jacob\com\variantutilities.java - import java.math.MathContext;
jacob-1.16.1\src\com\jacob\com\variantutilities.java - import java.math.BigDecimal;
jacob-1.16.1\src\com\jacob\com\variantutilities.java - import java.math.BigInteger;
jacob-1.16.1\src\com\jacob\com\variantutilities.java - import java.lang.reflect.Array;
```

EDIT:
I am not sure if this is actually an answer or not.

I fixed the problem by adding the websites WEB-INF\lib directory to the classpath for Tomcat. I feel that this is not the right answer because my understanding was that a website automatically includes the WEB-INF\lib into the classpath when the site is accessed.

What confuses the issue more is that the site has been running OK accessing other libs in that directory.

Having to add to the classpath is therefore a workaround for a misbehaving library. Which begs the question is a workaround the correct answer?? I guess I will leave the question open.

Answer (score 1):

This error means that the class `com.jacob.com.Dispatch` is using another class and it can't find it.

If you have the class source code, check to see what classes it uses and see that you have them in your classpath.

If you don't, try to look at the documentation ,find the jar that contains the missing classes and add it to the classpath.

Comment: I have gone through all the classes referenced by jacob (see Edit) but haven't been able to find the culprit.

Comment: Sometimes this error covers the real error, try enabling logging on trace level for the com.jacob lib so you can see exactly what is going on.